# probability of missing a free throw

Tags: probability

Given that the person has a FT% of 85.

What is the probability of having your first miss on or before your 9th shot?

I tried going with just multiplying the chance of missing which is 15% for each shot all together but that doesn't seem right. I would appreciate some direction on how to approach a problem like this.

Comment: What is the probability of making $9$ shots?

Comment: That should be (.85)^9 since each shot has a independent and has 85% chance to go in. I understand that much but not how  to calculate first miss.

Comment: So $0.85^9$ is the probability that the first miss does not happen on or before the $9$th shot. Which makes $1-0.85^9$ the probability that the first miss does happen on or before the $9$th shot

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ represent the event of having your first miss on or before your ninth shot (assuming that you shoot until you miss).

Then what is $A'$?  In other words, what is the **opposite** of having your first miss on or before your ninth shot?

> Having no misses in the first nine shots.  In other words, getting nine successes in a row.  What happens after the first nine shots is irrelevant.

Assuming that the shots are *independent* of one another, each with a probability of $0.85$, what is the probability of the opposite event occuring?

> $0.85^9$

Now, use the fact that $Pr(A) = 1- Pr(A')$ to find the probability you are looking for.

> $Pr(A) = 1-0.85^9$

Comment: Wouldn't 1- Pr(A') be the probability of not hitting any shots. Im having a bit of trouble seeing exacty what you are saying.

Comment: @Nubbins If we define the event $A$ as the event "gets the first miss on or before the ninth shot" the event $A'$ will be the event "gets the first miss *after* the ninth shot" i.e. hits the first nine shots.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not miss 9 shots in a row, your miss will come on the 10th shot or later. $0,85^9$ is a probability of 9 shots in a row. It is smth around 23%.

The probability to have your first miss on the 9-th shot or earlier is, correspondingly, 77%.

Multiplication of the chance of missing $0,15^9$ is a probability of 9 misses in a row, so it is not surprusing that you had a small number.